# How can I pass the latitude and longitude of my current location from one Activity to another in Android

Tags: php, android

How can I pass the latitude and longitude of my current location from one Activity to another Activity in Android? The second Activity contain a web view direct us to a php page. I want to pass these values to that php page as parameters append to URL.

Comment: Just put lat and long as string into intent in first activity, and getIntent parameters in second activity.

Comment: Here's a basic tutorial on using [HTML5's geolocation API](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp) with javascript. Once you get your values, you can insert them into your GET request

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send an object from one Android Activity to another using Intents?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139134/how-to-send-an-object-from-one-android-activity-to-another-using-intents)